# Displaying Widget Boxes Vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, inspinia

I currently have this kind of display for each record.

[image]

So per record I have two boxes which is Afternoon and Night. As you can see I am displaying each record horizontally with this code for reference:

```
<div id="record_box">

    <div class="row" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="widget style1 yellow-bg">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-4x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                        <span> Afternoon Total Bets </span>
                        <h2 class="font-bold" id="afternoon"></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="widget style1 lazur-bg">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <i class="fa fa-moon-o fa-4x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                        <span> Night Total Bets </span>
                        <h2 class="font-bold" id="night"></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="widget style1 yellow-bg">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-4x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                        <span> Afternoon Total Bets </span>
                        <h2 class="font-bold" id="afternoon"></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="widget style1 lazur-bg">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <i class="fa fa-moon-o fa-4x"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 text-right">
                        <span> Night Total Bets </span>
                        <h2 class="font-bold" id="night"></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So each record is this inside this block

`<div class="row" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">`

But my what if I want to display each record vertically? In a grid, 12 is the max size right? I have a fixed maximum number records that I need to display, and it's only 4. So I can make each record like `col-3`. What I mean also by vertical is if I have 1 record, Afternoon is on top, then night is bottom. Then the right will be blank. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create basic structure for you, now you can make necesssary changes in it.

css :

```
.panel-box {
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}

.panel-box .panel-heading {
  padding: 20px 10px;border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
.panel-box .panel-heading .fa {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 58px;
}
.panel-box .list-group-item {
  color: #777777;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
}

.panel-box .panel-body {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #777777;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
          <div class="panel panel-box">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-4x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body text-center">
              <span> Afternoon Total Bets </span>
              <h2 class="font-bold" id="afternoon"></h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-box">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <i class="fa fa-moon-o fa-4x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body text-center">
              <span> Night Total Bets </span>
              <h2 class="font-bold" id="night"></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
          <div class="panel panel-box">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-4x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body text-center">
              <span> Afternoon Total Bets </span>
              <h2 class="font-bold" id="afternoon"></h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-box">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <i class="fa fa-moon-o fa-4x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body text-center">
              <span> Night Total Bets </span>
              <h2 class="font-bold" id="night"></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
          <div class="panel panel-box">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-4x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body text-center">
              <span> Afternoon Total Bets </span>
              <h2 class="font-bold" id="afternoon"></h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-box">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <i class="fa fa-moon-o fa-4x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body text-center">
              <span> Night Total Bets </span>
              <h2 class="font-bold" id="night"></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
          <div class="panel panel-box">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <i class="fa fa-sun-o fa-4x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body text-center">
              <span> Afternoon Total Bets </span>
              <h2 class="font-bold" id="afternoon"></h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="panel panel-box">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <i class="fa fa-moon-o fa-4x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body text-center">
              <span> Night Total Bets </span>
              <h2 class="font-bold" id="night"></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This will generate structure like below image:
[image]